# Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Index 2 out of range [0..2) Volley Request Error

Tags: android, json, kotlin, android-volley, get-request

I know there are some other topics on the same subject but haven't solved my problem yet so I need some help if possible. I'm trying to send a GET Request to an API using volley in Android. My kotlin code is shown down bellow:

```
 val requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(c)
    val sharedPref = c.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE).getString(TEXT, "")
    Log.i("EDITTT", sharedPref)
    var  jsonArrayRequest = object : JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            Response.Listener { response ->
                var jsonArray: JSONArray = response
                for (item in 0..jsonArray.length()) {
                    var bookObject: JSONObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(item)
                    var title: String = bookObject.getString("title")
                    var author: String = bookObject.getString("author")
                    var publisher: String = bookObject.getString("publisher")
                    var date : String = bookObject.getString("date")
                    var bookItem: BookItem = BookItem(title, author, publisher)
                    bookData.add(bookItem)
                    println(bookData)
                }
                liveBookData.setValue(bookData)

            },
            Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                Log.i("ERRORRR", error.toString())
            })
    {
        @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
        override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {
            val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
            headers.put("Authorization", "$sharedPref");
            return headers
        }
    }
```

And I'm getting this ERROR:
**Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Index 2 out of range [0..2)**
If you have any suggestions, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `for (item in 0..jsonArray.length())` is an inclusive range, meaning that if `jsonArray`'s length is 2 (as in your case), it will loop 3 times: positions 0, 1 and 2.

Try using `until` instead, i.e. `for (item in 0 until jsonArray.length())`. The difference is that `until` doesn't include the last element, so it'll loop 2 times only: positions 0 and 1.

More info can be found at the official documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html#ranges-and-progressions